# Xamarin Windows Phone Store Package

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone, store

I' am in a bit of truble at the moment.

I try to build my Xamarin Windows Store App for publishing, but the Create App Packages Wizard, wont open I tried many solutions from the web, like unloading and reloading the project, or making a new project. But the wizard does not open with my solution i treid a normal Windows Phone app(no Silverlight), that worked but i could not Port my xamarin project to a standard Windows Phone App.

Has someone encountered a similar issue with Xamarin and Windows Phone,
or can anyone help to get my app into the Appstore?

Thanks.

I would have asked in the Xamarin Forum, but I cant reach them siche this morning.

And sorry for the engrish.

Comment: i can't post images but here is what i mean         http://imgur.com/w0JuEA5

Answer (score 2):

To submit package to the windows phone store you'll need to build your project (for ARM in Release mode to avoid warnings). Then on developer site when there is button to upload package you have to attach *.xap file from your project's bin\release folder (or bin folder you have specified). Then you can go through the next windows phone store app submitting steps.